# Python KIVY: how to implement recursive DropDown or recursive Spinner?

Tags: python, recursion, kivy, dropdown

I am programming an application that allows a teacher to create a school year, to add several classes in a year, in which he can add several students. There are 3 types of objects: School_Year, Class, Student. All of these objects are represented by a directory in the tree that contains children objects, apart from Student.

```
Tree architecture:
School_Year / Class / Student
```

Here is a representation of what I am trying to do:

**1. There is a home menu that displays all years and allows to add/delete years. When you click on a year, it shows you all the classes of this year:**
[image: YEAR menu 1]

**2. Imagine you click 2010-2011 year. It creates a recursive menu, and the 2012-2013 is pushed towards the bottom:**
[image: YEAR menu 2]

**3. Imagine you click "class A" , it shows you the list of the students of this clas with another recursive menu, and the "class B" is pushed to bottom:** 
[image: YEAR menu 3]

I can't do that because I'm too newbie at kivy but I tried the first rank of recursivety:
**.py:**

```
# coding: utf-8
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from functools import partial

class GUI(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Home(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Home, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # add a school year (parent "folder") on the home menu
    def add_year(self, grid, classname):
        # button of the year
        """ The values of this spinner are temporary, I don't know how to insert other child spinners inside
        I think I must replace the spinner by a Drop Down but I can't do it, I need some help"""
        left = Spinner(values = ["?", "??", "???"], text=classname.text, size = (32, 32), size_hint = (1, None))
        # the delete button of this year
        right = Button(background_color = (1,0,0,1), text="X", size = (32, 32), size_hint = (None, None))
        # equivalent of: on_press = self.del_year(grid, left, right) without NoneType error
        right.bind(on_press=partial(self.del_year, grid, left, right))
        # add these 2 buttons to the GridLayout
        grid.add_widget(left)
        grid.add_widget(right)
        # clear bottom's TextInput
        classname.text = ""
    # remove a school year from the home menu
    def del_year(self, grid, L, R, *args):
        # remove the two buttons from the GridLayout (year name button and delete button)
        grid.remove_widget(L)
        grid.remove_widget(R)

# load kivy file
Builder.load_file("nouv_test.kv")

class RunApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RunApp().run()
```

**.kv:**

```
#: kivy 1.10.0

<GUI>:
    Home:
        name: "home_screen"
        id: home

<Home>:

    GridLayout:
        rows: 3

        Button:
            text: "MY YEARS"
            size: (50, 50)
            size_hint: (1, None)
            background_color: (0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 1)

        ScrollView:


            size_hint:(1, .8)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            do_scroll_x: False

            GridLayout:
                id: home_scroll_grid
                cols: 2
                padding: 5
                spacing: 5
                height: self.minimum_height
                size_hint: (1, None)


        BoxLayout:

            padding: 5
            spacing: 5
            size: (42, 42)
            size_hint: (1, None)

            TextInput:
                id: year_name
                size: (32, 32)
                size_hint: (1, None)
                multiline: False

            Button:
                text: "+"
                background_color: (0,1,0,1)
                size: (32, 32)
                size_hint: (None, None)
                on_press: root.add_year(home_scroll_grid, year_name)
```

EDIT: I can also accept this kind of UI if the previous is too complicated:
[image: YEAR menu 4]

I gave as much information as possible because my problem is very specific, and uncommon, because it is very rare to use graphical recursion like that. So could someone give me some ways to try to do that ? Thanks.

Comment: One opinion: your GUI will look very overloaded. :P

Comment: I edited my topic. Wil it look overloaded even if I use a simplest kind of UI ? (look EDIT)